# Date Source Name Not Found

Tags: relational-database, delphi-10-seattle, firedac, ms-access-2016

When trying to connect to a database via FireDAC I get the following error:

[image: DSNameNotFound]

I checked and have confirmed that I have *MS Access database engine 2010* installed. I am running *Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit* and compiling my program in x64. My database was created in *MS Access 2016*. Here is my code for connecting to the database:

```
procedure TdmCallNotes.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  conCallNotes.Close;
  conCallNotes.DriverName := 'MSAcc';
  with conCallNotes.Params do
  begin
    Database := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'CallNote.accdb';
    DriverID := 'MSAcc';
  end;
  conCallNotes.LoginPrompt := False;
  conCallNotes.Connected := True;
  tblAccounts.Connection := conCallNotes;
  tblAccounts.TableName := 'tblAccounts';
  tblAccounts.Active := True;
  qryCompany.Connection := conCallNotes;
  qryContacts.Connection := conCallNotes;
end;
```

It seems I am able to connect when compiling in x86. Any ideas why I cannot compile in x64?

Answer (score 0):

You have no 64-bit ODBC driver for Microsoft Access installed on your system. You can get one in redistributable package [**from here**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) (**AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe**).

Just beware that FireDAC officially supports Microsoft Access only up to 2010 (at [**this time**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_Access_Database_(FireDAC))). But since it's an ODBC driver, I see no reason why version 2016 should not work properly.